# Can closed questions be voted on and are closed questions still eventually deleted?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I cannot find a definitive answer for these questions:

1. Can closed questions still be up/down voted?  If so why are votes allowed on questions that cannot have additional comments, answers and discussion added to?
2. Are closed questions still eventually deleted?  I see questions that were closed more than 1 year ago still on the system but have seen Meta posts stating that eventually closed questions are deleted.

Thanks!

Comment: Closed questions can be up/downvoted, we can add additional comments but we can't add answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, closed questions can be voted on. Closed questions can still be edited and commented upon, so voting is still allowed in case the question changes.  Closing a question only prevents new answers from being added.
2. Closing is supposed to be a step on the path towards deletion, but few questions are deleted automatically.  (They have to have negative score and no views for a long period of time before they'll be cleaned up automatically.)   For questions that are active, deletion takes 3-10 votes (based on the popularity of the question) from high-reputation members of the community or one vote from a diamond moderator.  If a closed question has any valuable information, or if there's a chance that it still might be edited into shape and reopened, it often just won't get enough votes to be deleted.